# Updating values in SQL Table based on same values in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I want to update values in tables that for any set of data in two columns, the third column is same. For example

```
Column1|  Column2|  Column3|
       |         |         |
      1|        2|        3|
      2|        1|        4|
      5|        6|        7|
```

After the query the result output should be

```
Column1|  Column2|  Column3|
       |         |         |
      1|        2|        3|
      2|        1|        3|
      5|        6|        7|
```

as in values (1, 2) and (2, 1) in column1 and column2 should have same values for column3

Comment: In what way do these have the same data?

Comment: as in values (1, 2) and (2, 1) in column1 and column2 should have same values for column3

Comment: How is the desired `column3` value determined?

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: the column3 value is any random value. Created by rand() function.

Comment: i am using mssql server management studio 2012

Comment: He means that if column 1 and column 2 are the same (but in different order), the rows should show the same for column 3.

Comment: How do you determine which value you want in column3 if there are different values for column3?

Comment: The one that comes first. As in the top one

Comment: There is no "first".  Tables are not inherently ordered in SQL.

Comment: Can there be two or more rows having row1.column1 = row2.column1 AND row1.column2 = row2.column2?

Comment: nope. column1 and column2 uniquely identify the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self-join:

```
UPDATE your_table t1 -- Your table goes here
SET [Column3] = rand()
FROM your_table t2 -- and here
WHERE (t1.[Column1] = t2.[Column1] AND t1.[Column2] = t2.[Column2]) OR
    (t1.[Column1] = t2.[Column2] AND t1.[Column2] = t2.[Column1])
```

Comment: I hope it works. I couldn't test it since SQL Fiddle doesn't seem to work right now.